# How to retrieve the results of PLSQL procedure to java class

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

How can we retrieve the results of pl sql procedure to java class and maniupulate inside java ?

Comment: by writing code...you want a more specific answer? Then ask a specific question...

Comment: I need an idea not the code what are the ways we can accmplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `CallableStatement` to execute the procedure and then `getResultSet()` for multiple result sets use `getMoreResults()`.

You can refer this java code,

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call simpleprocedure(?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "param");
ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
```